# What's the best way to compute the coefficients of a polynomial from its roots?

Tags: matlab, polynomials

The `poly` function takes the roots of a polynomial as the input and returns the polynomial's coefficients. What is the underlying algorithm?

Is there a better way to compute the coefficients of a polynomial from its roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

- To obtain the polynomial *p*(*x*) (with leading coefficient `1`) you need to **multiply** all terms of the form *x*−*r*, where *r* is a root. (Multiple roots should be considered several times according to their multiplicities.)
- Multiplication of polynomials is equivalent to convolution. In fact, the [documentation of `conv`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) says

  > `w = conv(u,v)` returns the **convolution** of vectors `u` and `v`. If `u` and `v` are vectors of polynomial coefficients, convolving them is equivalent to multiplying the two polynomials.

So:

```
roots = [1 -2 3]; %// input (roots)
result = 1;  %// initiallize
for r = roots
    result = conv(result, [1 -r]);
end
```

In this example the result is

```
result =
     1    -2    -5     6
```

which is the same vector that [`poly`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/poly.html) returns.

Alternatively, you can do the convolution **manually**:

```
roots = [1 -2 3]; %// input (roots)
result = 1;  %// initiallize
for r = roots
    result = [result 0] + [0 -r*result];
end
```

This is equivalent to the following code with **explicit loops**, which should be closer to a C++ implementation:

```
roots = [1 -2 3]; %// input (roots)
result = nan(1,numel(roots)+1);  %// preallocate. Values will be overwritten
result(1) = 1; %// initiallize
for n = 1:numel(roots)
    result(n+1) = -roots(n)*result(n); %// update from right to left, due to overwriting
    for k = n:-1:2
        result(k) = result(k) - roots(n)*result(k-1);
    end
end
```

Comment: I am wondering whether this can be implemented easily in C++ too?

Comment: I don't know much about C++, but I've added a new version which should be close to what would be done in that language. Please check edited answer

Answer (score 4):

Since you solicited for a c++ answer.
A typical implementation would look like.

```
std::vector<int> poly( std::vector<int> roots )
{
    std::vector<int> result{1};
    for( size_t i = 0 ; i < roots.size() ; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<int> temp{result.begin(),result.end()};

        for(auto & item : temp )
            item *= ( -roots[i] );

        result.push_back(0);
        for( size_t j = 1 ; j < result.size() ; ++j)
        {
            result[j] += temp[j-1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Why would you use `int` for the poly and temp vector? I suggest a floating-point datatype.