# The Lagrange polynomial

Tags: c++, math, polynomials

**My program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string lagrange(vector<pair<double, double>>& points) {
    int n = points.size();
    string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        string term = to_string(points[i].second);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                term += " * (x - " + to_string(points[j].first) + ") / (" + to_string(points[i].first - points[j].first) + ")";
            }
        }
        if (i < n - 1) {
            term += " +";
        }
        result += term;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of points: ";
    cin >> n;

    vector<pair<double, double>> points;
    cout << "Enter the dots in the format x y:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        points.push_back(make_pair(x, y));
    }

    string result = lagrange(points);
    cout << "The Lagrange polynomial for the introduced points:\n" << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How to derive the Lagrange polynomial in the form of a polynomial? That is, not (x - x1) * (x - x2) * ... (x - xi), but in the form a1 * x^n + a2 * x^n-1+ ... + an

Comment: Here's a suggestion, work though a few examples by hand, see if you can work out the general method on pen and paper. Then translate that method into code. This is normal when you are trying to figure out a tricky algorithm.

Comment: Seems like a power set construction (or equivalent) would be part of the algorithm. The simple way to do that is with recursion.

Comment: Use a polynomial class.

Comment: See <https://stackoverflow.com/q/32932245/1100107>.